# ResponceEntity. The controller truncates the JSON portion of the response

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I have a controller that sends a request to an external API using RestTemplate and gets a data structure. This structure it should return, but when using my controller sometimes the end of the JSON response is dropped.

I tried to customize RestTemplate and increase the response size in application.yaml

My controller:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/weather/lat={lat}&lon={lon}")
    @Cacheable(value = "root", key = "{#lat , #lon}")
    public ResponseEntity<Root> getWeather(@PathVariable("lat") String lat, @PathVariable("lon") String lon) {
        try{
            String request = String.format("%s?lat=%s&lon=%s&units=metric&appid=%s",
                    weatherUrl, lat, lon, appId);
            return restTemplate.getForEntity(request, Root.class);
        }catch (RestClientException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Example of a truncated query:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lat": 1.4,
        "lon": 2.33
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 804,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "overcast clouds",
            "icon": "04n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 26.15,
        "feels_like": 26.15,
        "temp_min": 26.15,
        "temp_max": 26.15,
        "pressure": 1014,
        "humidity": 79,
        "sea_level": 1014,
        "grnd_level": 1014
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 6.34,
        "deg": 198,
        "gust": 6.08
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 100
    },
    "dt": 1696111416,
    "sys": {
        "sunrise": 1696052261,
        "sunset": 1696095829
    },
    "timezone": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "name":"co
```

application.yaml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: weather-service
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        instance:
          api-gateway-port: 17957
          management-base-url: http://localhost:${spring.boot.admin.client.instance.api-gateway-port}

eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.value}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8888/eureka/

appid: *********************


url:
  external-api:
    weather: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather

server:
  port: 0
```

Comment: Please, provide us your configuration yml or properties.

Comment: Added application.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, ResponseEntity is incorrectly accounting for Content-length header. This occurred because the external API could return an object with null fields. To fix it, you need to allow jackson to pass null fields using `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation which is placed above POJO. By putting it over all serializable fields in this structure I got:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lat": 1.4,
        "lon": 2.33
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 804,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "overcast clouds",
            "icon": "04n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 26.15,
        "feels_like": 26.15,
        "temp_min": 26.15,
        "temp_max": 26.15,
        "pressure": 1014,
        "humidity": 79,
        "sea_level": 1014,
        "grnd_level": 1014
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 6.34,
        "deg": 198,
        "gust": 6.08
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 100
    },
    "dt": 1696111416,
    "sys": {
        "sunrise": 1696052261,
        "sunset": 1696095829
    },
    "timezone": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "name": "",
    "cod": 200
}
```

I tried to do something different and the changes in my method gave the correct result too.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/weather/lat={lat}&lon={lon}")
    @Cacheable(value = "root", key = "{#lat , #lon}")
    public ResponseEntity<Root> getWeather(@PathVariable("lat") String lat, @PathVariable("lon") String lon) {
        try{
            String request = String.format("%s?lat=%s&lon=%s&units=metric&appid=%s",
                    weatherUrl, lat, lon, appId);
            var r = restTemplate.getForObject(request, Root.class);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(r);
        }catch (RestClientException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug in Spring. If you wanted to keep your nulls you could return a `StreamingResponseBody` and write your `Root` object to the output stream using the `writeValue` method of `ObjectMapper`. I think this should force a chunked response encoding as well as being more efficient on memory if you have a very large json object.